# openshift nodejs copy written file to repo

Tags: deployment, hook, openshift

I have a nodejs app on openshift an one of the things the app does is write a text file.

Problem is, whenever I update code in the app and deploy it, the text file is gone because the live repo address has changed.

Is there a way using build hooks to get any files saved in a particular folder, add them to my git repo and then deploy the app? I'm not completely clear what I would write in a hook or what to save the hook as so any help would be awesome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the file inside of your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR so that it will not get over-written each time.  You can not copy the file into your git repo on the gear.  You might want to try something like the WordPress cartridge does, which is create a symlink (using the deploy action hook) to create a folder in your repo dir that is linked to your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy)